# How do I return multiple column values as new rows in Oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table where multiple account numbers are associated with different IDs(DR_NAME). Each account could have as few as 0 accounts, and as many as 16.  I believe UNPIVOT would work, but I'm on Oracle 10g, which does not support this.

```
DR_NAME   ACCT1   ACCT2   ACCT3   ACC4  
======================================
SMITH     1234
JONES     5678    2541    2547
MARK      NULL    
WARD      8754    6547
```

I want to display a new line for each name with only 1 account number per line

```
DR_NAME   ACCT
==============
SMITH     1234
JONES     5678
JONES     2541
JONES     2547
MARK      NULL
WARD      8754
WARD      6547
```

Comment: How many rows of data do you need to do this for in a single query, and do you need to just select this data or insert it into a table?

Comment: @DavidAldridge About 1500 rows of initial data, which I'm estimating may make about 6000 rows when each DR_NAME is paired with only 1 ACCT.  It will need to be inserted into a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle 10g does not have an `UNPIVOT` function but you can use a `UNION ALL` query to unpivot the columns into rows:

```
select t1.DR_NAME, d.Acct
from yourtable t1
left join
(
  select DR_NAME, ACCT1 as Acct
  from yourtable
  where acct1 is not null
  union all
  select DR_NAME, ACCT2 as Acct
  from yourtable
  where acct2 is not null
  union all
  select DR_NAME, ACCT3 as Acct
  from yourtable
  where acct3 is not null
  union all
  select DR_NAME, ACCT4 as Acct
  from yourtable
  where acct4 is not null
) d
  on t1.DR_NAME = d.DR_NAME;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8801/8).

This query uses a `UNION ALL` to convert the columns into rows.  I included a `where` clause to remove any `null` values, otherwise you will get multiple rows for each account where the acct value is null.  Excluding the `null` values will drop the `dr_name = Mark` which you showed that you want in the final result.  To include the rows that only have `null` values, I added the join to the table again.

Comment: You'd want to add predicates to avoid returning nulls

Comment: @DavidAldridge You are correct, I altered it slightly because they actually want to return all `DR_NAME` values.  If I exclude `null`, then they will not get `Mark`

Comment: @user2249376 I am not sure what you mean?  I am showing based on your sample the multiple rows for each dr_name -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8801/10 - Jones has 3 rows, Mark =1, Smith = 1 and Ward = 2

Comment: @bluefeet I will check my code.  That does appear to work. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @bluefeet Got it!  Didn't read all of my results. I'm using Toad, and had to add the "ORDER BY" clause to group the DR_NAMES together

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way I know is to do a cross join with some logic:

```
select *
from (select t.dr_name,
             (case when n.n = 1 then acct1
                   when n.n = 2 then acct2
                   when n.n = 3 then acct3
                   when n.n = 4 then acct4
              end) as acct
      from t cross join
           (select 1 as n from dual union all
            select 2 from dual union all
            select 3 from dual union all
            select 4 from dual
           ) n
     ) s
where acct is not null
```

The `union all` approach typical results in scanning the table once for each subquery.  This approach will typically scan the table once.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in inserting these records then take a look at multitable insert -- a single scan of the data and multiple rows generated, so it's very efficient.

Code examples here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604

Note that you can reference the same table multiple times, using syntax along the lines of ...

```
insert all
  when acct1 is not null then into target_table (..) values (dr_name,acct1)
  when acct2 is not null then into target_table (..) values (dr_name,acct2)
  when acct3 is not null then into target_table (..) values (dr_name,acct3)
  when acct4 is not null then into target_table (..) values (dr_name,acct4)
select
  dr_name,
  acct1,
  acct2,
  acct3,
  acct4
from my_table.
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this.  I have a solution which currently works, but this may be more efficient.